# How to use a NumPy slice as a function argument?

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, slice

Currently extracting frames from a video to be processed later on. I have different areas of the video frames that I want to process so I need to be able to pass a numpy slice into a variable to be used as the function's argument. What's the syntax for that?

`frame[5:49, 879:938]` is the slice that I would like to use in a variable to be passed as the 3rd argument of the `extractFrames` function.

Here's my code:

```
def extractFrames(video_file, folder):
    try:
        os.mkdir(folder)
    except:
        shutil.rmtree(folder)
        os.mkdir(folder)
    capture = cv2.VideoCapture(video_file)
    count = 0
    while (capture.isOpened()):
        # Capture frame-by-frame
        ret, frame = capture.read()
        if ret == True:
            print('Read %d frame: ' % count, ret)
            cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(folder, "{:d}.jpg".format(count)), frame[5:49, 879:938])  # save frame as JPEG file
            count += 1
        else:
            break
    # When everything done, release the capture
    capture.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say `frame[5:49, 879:938]` you are indexing into `frame` using a pair of `slice`s.  The `slice` type is built in to Python, and you can pass two of them to your function like this:

```
extractFrames("filename", "folder", x=slice(5, 49), y=slice(879, 938))
```

Defining your function like this:

```
def extractFrames(video_file, folder, x=slice(None), y=slice(None)):
    ...frame[x_slice, y_slice]...
```

The default arguments will take the whole frame...you can omit them if you want the slicing to be mandatory.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to construct slice objects and pass those around.

You can just pass the bounds around:

```py
def extractFrames(..., bounds):
    (y0, y1, x0, x1) = bounds
    ...
    subregion = frame[y0:y1, x0:x1]
    ....

extractFrames(..., (5, 49, 879, 938))
```

This also allows you to pass `None` for any bounds, so the slice becomes an "all-slice".

Or pass `(x, y, w, h)`-style numbers, if you have those anyway, and then slice `[y:y+h, x:x+w]`.